# Find Profile by VanityName API

Tags: linkedin-api, spring-social-linkedin, omniauth-linkedin

I'm trying to fetch linkedIn profile data using the vanityName API. To use this, I need the 'r_compliance_2l' permission. I just went through the documents, I'm not able to find any information on how to obtain permission. Can someone assist me?